# How to insert jQuery code in Avada theme?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I want to insert a simple jQuery code in my Wordpress theme (Avada), something [like this](http://codepen.io/lormski/pen/meXadK/):

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({ show: { effect: "blind", direction: "right", duration:300 }});
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();

    var btn = $('#accordion li a');
    var wrapper = $('#accordion li');

    $(btn).on('click', function() {
        $(btn).removeClass('active');
        $(btn).parent().find('.addon').removeClass('fadein');

        $(this).addClass('active');
        $(this).parent().find('.addon').addClass('fadein');
    });
});
```

In a page, but it doesn't work.

I tried to use different classes to all the HTML elements and to insert my code with a plugin named "CSS & Javascript Tool box", but it didn't helped.

Comment: did you replace the '$' sign to 'jQuery'?

Comment: add it to wp_footer and replace $ with jQuery please and futher reading here:https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer

Comment: How exactly did you insert your JS "in a page"? Did you added it in a script tag inside the page template?

Comment: I trid to replace $ by JQuery, but it's do not work :(

Comment: I used a plugin name CSS & Javascript toolbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First don't use any CSS/JS plugin, it's a terrible idea as such plugins are usually the reason for major security issues and doesn't provide any good maintainability.

Here is the proper way to add Javascript in Wordpress :

In your child theme (because you created a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to Avada in order to be able to update it at any time, right? :) ), add the following function in your *functions.php* file:

```
function my_theme_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('jquery-ui', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.11.2', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui');
    wp_register_script('tabs-scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/tabs-script.js', array('jquery', 'jquery-ui'), '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('tabs-scripts');
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-style', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_scripts');
```

This will tell Wordpress to add the appropriate script tag to link to *tabs-scripts.js* located in your theme js directory at the footer of every page, and to load the jQuery UI dependency. See [`wp_register_script` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) for reference.

Then, create your *tabs-scripts.js* file in your js directory and add the following script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    if($('#tabs').length && $('#accordion').length) {
        $("#tabs").tabs({ show: { effect: "blind", direction: "right", duration:300 }});
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();

        var btn = $('#accordion li a');
        var wrapper = $('#accordion li');

        $(btn).on('click', function() {
            $(btn).removeClass('active');
            $(btn).parent().find('.addon').removeClass('fadein');

            $(this).addClass('active');
            $(this).parent().find('.addon').addClass('fadein');
        });
    }
}
```

This will ensure two things:

- That `$` is available and reference to `jQuery`
- And the appropriate DOM elements `#tabs` and `#accordion` are in the page before running the script.

If it doesn't work check that the script is added to the page, and that the `($('#tabs').length && $('#accordion').length))` is fulfilled.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! 

I have a Child theme yes ;)

I just tested your advices and the script is not added in the page. do you know where can i put the file in the FTP ? Thanks

Comment: Your js file should be in `wp-content/themes/<your-child-theme>/js/`, and you should add the function in `wp-content/themes/<your-child-theme>/functions.php`. If you did this right and it still doesn't work, check if your theme _footer.php_ file does contain a call to `wp_footer()` function.

Comment: I check the footer.php and i found this : 
<?php
  wp_footer();

  // Echo the scripts added to the "before </body>" field in Theme Options
  echo Avada()->settings->get( 'space_body' );
  ?>

But i cannot found the tabs-script.js in the page

Comment: Did you added the exact code I pasted in _functions.php_? You need the function + the `add_action` call.

Comment: Yes i do it exactly like you explain it

Comment: Then there is no reason it shouldn't work - if you added the right code in your child theme _functions.php_ and `wp_footer();` is being called in the _footer.php_ being used, it should generate the appropriate script tag. If you look at the source of your page(ctrl+u) and search for `tabs-script` you really don't find any reference of it?

Comment: Just noticed that I missed the `wp_enqueue_script` in my example - check updated answer and try with it.

Comment: It works finally ! You 're right. Thanks, but there is an error in the console :

x GET http://www-edi.donzat.net/wp-content/themes/Avada-Child-Theme/js/tabs-script.js?ver=1.0

Comment: in fact, it did tells : failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)

Comment: Well it seems the file is not found, you need to create that _tab-scripts.js_ file in the **js** folder inside your child theme and put your js inside it.

Comment: Yep, i just checked the file, the name was the problem, i forgot a "s" it's good now, but there is an other JS error : 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token at this  :   

 .length)")"

The parenthesis seems wrong in the code

Comment: And if i correct it, there is a new js error : 

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function

Comment: Yes there was a parenthesis that shouldn't be there. If `$.tabs` is not a function it means that you're missing the tabs library. You need to include jquery ui as well, just as the example you linked in codepen. I updated my answer to show how to include jquery ui in Wordpress.

Comment: Ok i will include jquery ui then. Thank you very very much. You rock !

Answer (score 19):

You are using Avada theme, go to theme options->Advance->Code Fields (Tracking etc.), you will see three text boxes you need to add your code in the second box (Space before ).
Place code inside  tags. I am attaching the screenshot.[image]

Comment: Thx for our help, but i have try this between <script> but it dont work at all. The code is added in the page, but doesn't work.

Comment: do you see any error, try doing inspect element, see if you get any error

Comment: also make it document ready      jQuery(document).ready(function($)

Comment: Thanks ! I have this error : 

(index):218 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).tabs is not a function

Comment: .tabs is jQuery UI function, Please if jQuery UI script is loaded or not, if not please add jQuery UI file. you can get more info about tabs here https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Answer (score 0):

Simply add your script code to your *functions.php* file. What this does is centralize your script code without much work. Your only requisite is that you have JQuery defined before you consume the script.

There are many ways to solve what you are asking but I tend to lean towards getting the information from the source. The link below will hopefully help.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Comment: You should avoid to put your JS code directly in your templates as it is not easily maintainable - all of the JS should be enqueued in order to provide version and dependence control. This is very important in term of performance too, as a separate file can be cached, minified... See [Is it better to put the JS code on the html file or in an external file?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/223921)

Comment: Apologies, I meant functions.php.

Comment: Thanks ! I have tried the Function.php but it doesnt work