# How to disable/enable a button depending on a dropdown selection (with external links) using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown with some options to choose, which lead to an external link. This works fine so far, but I'd like to have the button disabled when nothing is selected. As a non-developer I couldn't put it together just yet. Any ideas?

```js
function goToNewPage() {
    if(document.getElementById('target').value){
        window.open(document.getElementById('target').value);
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="dropdown">
<select name="list" id="target">
<option selected>Please select one</option>
<option value="http://search.msn.com/">MSN Search</option>
<option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
<option value="http://www.search.com/">Search.com</option>
<option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">Dogpile</option>
</select>
<input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.list)" class="gobutton">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you could use:

```
// binding the anonymous function of the on() method as
// the event-handler for the 'change' event:
$('#target').on('change', function(){

    // finds the next sibling <input> element with the '.gobutton'
    // class-name:
    $(this).next('.gobutton')
      // and sets its 'disabled' property to true if
      // the value of the <select> is equal to the 'Please select one'
      // string:
      .prop('disabled', this.value === 'Please select one');

// triggers the 'change' event on page load in order that the
// anonymous function disables the <input> on page-load:
}).change();
```

```js
function goToNewPage() {
  if (document.getElementById('target').value) {
    window.open(document.getElementById('target').value);
  }
}
$('#target').on('change', function() {
  $(this).next('.gobutton').prop('disabled', this.value === 'Please select one');
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="dropdown">
  <select name="list" id="target">
    <option selected>Please select one</option>
    <option value="http://search.msn.com/">MSN Search</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.search.com/">Search.com</option>
    <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">Dogpile</option>
</select>
  <input type=button value="Go" class="gobutton" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.list)" class="gobutton">
</form>
```

Another way to use the above, without hard-coding specific values is to rely upon the `defaultValue` of the `<select>` element:

```
// binding the anonymous function of the on() method as
// the event-handler for the 'change' event:
$('#target').on('change', function(){
    // caching the <option> elements of the <select>
    // element:
    let opts = this.options,

        // finding the index of the currently-selected
        // <option> from the options:
        currentSelected = this.selectedIndex;

    // finding the next <input> sibling, if that
    // <input> sibling has the class-name of
    // 'gobutton':
    $(this).next('.gobutton')
        // setting the disabled property to true if:
        // the currently-selected <option> is the
        // defaultSelected property is true/truthy
        // (this returns Boolean true if the
        // <option> has the 'selected' property or
        // is selected on page-load in the browser:
        .prop('disabled', opts[currentSelected].defaultSelected);

// triggers the 'change' event on page load in order that the
// anonymous function disables the <input> on page-load:
}).change();
```

```js
function goToNewPage() {
  if (document.getElementById('target').value) {
    window.open(document.getElementById('target').value);
  }
}
$('#target').on('change', function() {
  let opts = this.options,
    currentSelected = this.selectedIndex;
  $(this).next('.gobutton').prop('disabled', opts[currentSelected].defaultSelected);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="dropdown">
  <select name="list" id="target">
    <option selected>Please select one</option>
    <option value="http://search.msn.com/">MSN Search</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.search.com/">Search.com</option>
    <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">Dogpile</option>
</select>
  <input type=button value="Go" class="gobutton" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.list)" class="gobutton">
</form>
```

It's worth noting that, since you've tagged this question with jQuery, it might be easier to use jQuery to bind your original function also:

```
function goToNewPage() {
  window.open(document.getElementById('target').value);
}

// here we bind the goToNewPage() function (note the deliberate
// lack of parentheses, we want to bind the function not the
// return value of the function) as the event-handler for the
// 'click' event:
$('.gobutton').on('click', goToNewPage);

$('#target').on('change', function() {
  let opts = this.options,
    currentSelected = this.selectedIndex;
  $(this).next('.gobutton').prop('disabled', opts[currentSelected].defaultSelected);
}).change();
```

```js
function goToNewPage() {
  window.open(document.getElementById('target').value);
}

$('.gobutton').on('click', goToNewPage);

$('#target').on('change', function() {
  let opts = this.options,
    currentSelected = this.selectedIndex;
  $(this).next('.gobutton').prop('disabled', opts[currentSelected].defaultSelected);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="dropdown">
  <select name="list" id="target">
    <option selected>Please select one</option>
    <option value="http://search.msn.com/">MSN Search</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.search.com/">Search.com</option>
    <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">Dogpile</option>
</select>
  <input type=button value="Go" class="gobutton" class="gobutton">
</form>
```

The prime benefit of binding functionality with jQuery – or with JavaScript in general – is that it removes the obtrusive JavaScript from the page and makes it easier to bind, or remove, the same function to, or from, multiple elements without having to go through the HTML to find those relevant elements.

If, however, you'd rather use JavaScript without an additional library the above functionality is easily attainable:

```
// defining variables using the 'const' statement, this
// prevents these variables from being changed elsewhere
// (although new properties can still be assigned to the
// cached variables):
// here we define a new Event that we can listen for later,
// and dispatch on page-load to trigger the method bound
// as the event-handler for that event:
const changeEvent = new Event('change'),

 // because we refer to this node twice it's worth caching
 // to avoid having to look up the element more than once:
      target = document.getElementById('target');

function goToNewPage() {
  window.open(document.getElementById('target').value);
}

// here we use Array.from() to convert the NodeList
// returned by document.querySelectorAll(), which
// finds elements matching the supplied CSS selector,
// in an Array in order to use Array methods (it's worth
// noting that many browsers supply a NodeList.forEach()
// method, but not all do unfortunately):
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input.gobutton'))

  // here we use Array.prototype.forEach() (instead of
  // the sometimes present NodeList.prototype.forEach()
  // in order to reduce the chance of errors being thrown)
  // to iterate over each Node in the Array of Nodes:
  .forEach(function(button) {
    // 'button' refers to the current Node of the Array
    // of Nodes over which we're iterating, and here
    // we bind the goToNewPage() function (again: note
    // the deliberate lack of parentheses) as the
    // event-handler of the 'click' event:
    button.addEventListener('click', goToNewPage);
  });

// hwere we use the addEventListener() method to bind the
// anonymous function as the event-handler for the 'change'
// event:
target
  .addEventListener('change', function() {

    // caching the <option> elements:
    let opts = this.options,

    // retrieving the inde of the currently-selected 
    // <option> element's index:
      currentSelected = this.selectedIndex,

    // finding the '.gobutton' element within the same
    // parentNode as the target Node:
      gobutton = this.parentNode.querySelector('.gobutton');

    // if a matching element was found (document.querySelector()
    // returns the first matching element if one, or more, exists
    // or null if no matching element was found):
    if (gobutton) {

      // here we set the disabled property of the gobutton
      // to true if the default-selected <option> is selected,
      // or to false if any other <option> is selected:
      gobutton.disabled = opts[currentSelected].defaultSelected;
    }
  });

  target.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

```js
const changeEvent = new Event('change'),
      target = document.getElementById('target');
function goToNewPage() {
  window.open(document.getElementById('target').value);
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input.gobutton'))
  .forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', goToNewPage);
  });

target
  .addEventListener('change', function() {
    let opts = this.options,
      currentSelected = this.selectedIndex,
      gobutton = this.parentNode.querySelector('.gobutton');
    if (gobutton) {
      gobutton.disabled = opts[currentSelected].defaultSelected;
    }
  });
  
  target.dispatchEvent(changeEvent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="dropdown">
  <select name="list" id="target">
    <option selected>Please select one</option>
    <option value="http://search.msn.com/">MSN Search</option>
    <option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
    <option value="http://www.search.com/">Search.com</option>
    <option value="http://www.dogpile.com/">Dogpile</option>
</select>
  <input type=button value="Go" class="gobutton">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't see any effect just yet. It should be added just in addition to the function I already have right?

Comment: If you look at the (now corrected) snippet that should show you how to use it alongside your current function.

Comment: Cool now I see that it works thanks! The source of the jquery-library was missing. Now I just need to figure out how to embed this in my wordpress theme (Avada) so that it works there as well. Do you also know how to solve this?

Comment: I'm afraid not, it's been nearly a decade since I last looked at Wordpress, and even when I *did* use Wordpress it pained me a little. That question might already be answered over on [wordpress.se] though.

Comment: Ok, I will check that out. I found some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271931/how-to-insert-jquery-code-in-avada-theme) as well. Thanks anyway!