# How to add the Javascripts into Avada Footer in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, footer

How can added the Javascript into Avada Theme Footer.I try added the scripts into Theme option -> Advanced -> Code Field -> Tracking Code / Space before < /head> / Space before < /body> , function.php and footer.php also don't work for my footer scripts. The source code is using inspect to view, so I don't know where can edit it as  become the source code like this `<a href="#nav_menu-10" onclick="this.classList.toggle('toggle');">ABOUT</a>`, so I try using Javascript to add but it doesn't work. Any solution can helps?

Scripts

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#collapsible-widget-2 a").attr('href',"onclick='this.classList.toggle('toggle')'");
});
</script>
```

Source code that script I want to add into a href: [image]

Comment: Check in you themes settings for something like "Custom scripts" where you can add your JS. I haven't work with Avada but there should be some place available for "Custom scripts". Actually you should check this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271931/how-to-insert-jquery-code-in-avada-theme

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert jQuery code in Avada theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37271931/how-to-insert-jquery-code-in-avada-theme)

Comment: Dont post code as a screenshot. We want to copy it, search engines want to index it

Comment: Hi,Lonely the source code is using inspection to view because I don't know the actual source code in where so I just can screenshot to post.